# Checkbox checked when editing HABTM models

Tags: cakephp, checkbox, cakephp-2.0

I need a help

I have 2 models: Attorney and Powers.

Where: `Attorney` HABTM `Powers`

When I add a new Attorney, I select many checkboxes that correspond to the Powers.

My question is: When I edit an Attorney, how do make the checkboxes appear selected? They'r do'nt.

The the part of edit.ctp

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Poderes:</label>
<div class="controls">
<?php foreach ($poderes as $power):  ?>
<div class="checkbox tooltip" title="<?php echo $power['Power']['texto'] ?>">
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $power['Power']['id'] ?>"  />
<label><?php echo $power['Power']['resumo'] ?></label>
</div>
```

My edit controller.

```
 function edit($id = null) {


$this->set('poderes',$this->Attorney->Power->find('all'));
$this->Attorney->id = $id;

     if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Attorney->read();

    } else {

        if ($this->Attorney->save($this->request->data) {


        $this->Session->setFlash('Usuário editado com sucesso!', 'default', array('class' => 'flash_sucess'));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'pesquisar'));
}
}
```

EDIT: IMAGE OF THE RESULT USING `$this->Form->input('Power', array('checkbox' => 'multiple'));`

[image: The result of the first anwser]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make proper use of the Form helper, then all you need to do is reading a list of `Power`s, and passing `checkbox` as the value for the `multiple` option to `FormHelper::input()`. CakePHP will do the rest and check the appropriate checkboxes.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::input
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::select

Also you should follow CakePHPs naming conventions and use english for model/(view)variable names etc, ie don't use `poderes`, use the appropriate plural of `Power`, which is `powers`.

**Controller**

```
...
$this->set('powers', $this->Attorney->Power->find('list'));
$this->Attorney->id = $id;
...
```

Note that [`Model::find('list')`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) requires proper use of [`Model::$displayField`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#model-displayfield)!

**View**

```
...
echo $this->Form->input('Power', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));
...
```

Comment: Hi!! I think that I don't understand exactly. Ok, I add the `$this->Form->input('Power', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));` but is not working yet. Thanks!!! =)